# How to loop an echoed variable?

Tags: php

I currently tried this:

```
$custom_image = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-4');
$custom_image = htmlspecialchars_decode($custom_image);
$custom_image = nl2br($custom_image);
$custom_image = preg_replace('/<br \/>/iU', '', $custom_image);
foreach($custom_image as $img) {
    echo $img;
}
```

But I get

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...

Comment: You loop an array not string values! Why looping at this point? Btw: You can not do stuff on `echoed` content, because it is outputted and not anymore in your hand.

Comment: What does `usp_get_meta` returns? Does it contains image per line?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions because that will output a series of `<li>` actually, that variable has plain text with few `<li>`

Comment: @Justinas it has a series of `<li>` which I inserted in a custom field

Comment: And what magic does make an array out of `<li>`s? Why are you thinging in that way?

Comment: *A series of `<li>` assigned to `$custom_image`!*

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I'm not, just hoping for magic actually :) - SO basically I would need to loop within the actual result i guess

Comment: Plz post what comes from `usp_get_meta()` into your question, maybe it will get clearer for us.

Comment: $custom_image[]

Comment: Why can't you just output all `li`? Like `echo "<ul>{$custom_image}</ul>"`

Comment: @revo Yes indeed, it is more complicated than that. I am placing a series of `<li>` in a custom field since those `<li>` are first created by the user on the front end, placing the html as plain text into a textarea and sending it to backend in a custom field, then i read the custom field. I want to control now each single `<li>`

Answer (score 1):

Just an simple assumption to get it fixed:

Change
`$custom_image = preg_replace('/<br \/>/iU', '', $custom_image);`

to
`$custom_image = explode('<br />',$custom_image);`

Then you can loop it.

Comment: that's it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @RobertoMarras Yep it fixed this, but did you know why and can that help you in the future?! But, always nice to help

Comment: yup i got it, loop is possible only on an array, yet by doing explode, we are separating each thing inside it, so we can loop them as single elements. Ok a bit plain but that should be the general concept, so i've just learned, thanks :)